Disable UIScrollView bounce at both ends
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        setupScrollView()
        setupViewControllers()
    }
    
    func setupScrollView() {
        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
        }
    }
    
    func setupViewControllers() {
        let firstVC = DetailViewController()
        let secondVC = TabViewController()
        
        addChild(firstVC)
        addChild(secondVC)
        
        scrollView.addSubview(firstVC.view)
        scrollView.addSubview(secondVC.view)
        
        firstVC.view.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.equalTo(scrollView)
            make.width.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
            make.height.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
        }
        
        secondVC.view.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(firstVC.view.snp.bottom)
            make.leading.trailing.equalTo(scrollView)
            make.width.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
            make.height.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)
            make.bottom.equalTo(scrollView)
        }
        
        firstVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        secondVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        let contentHeight = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.height * 2
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width, height: contentHeight)
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
        let scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height
        
        // 아래쪽으로만 바운스 막기
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y > contentHeight - scrollViewHeight {
            scrollView.contentOffset.y = contentHeight - scrollViewHeight
        }
        
        // 위쪽으로만 바운스 막기
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
            scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
        }
    }
}

Simulator screenshot
When I drag down, the view above is slightly visible.
When "scrollView.contentOffset.y>contentHeight - scrollViewHeight" and "scrollView.contentOffset.y<0", is there a way for srollView to not be bound and not see each other's views?
I looked it up on StackOverflow but I used the same method and I don't know why it doesn't work beautifully
